# how to fix "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Operator '<-' not implemented " in R

Tags: r

I am solving a data mining problem so there is an error saying

> "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Operator '<-' not implemented" how can i fix this

```
E <- editset(expression(
  Age >- 0,
  Age <- 150))
```

Comment: Could you add what packages you're using and full code plus data that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Is `Age >- 0` what you mean to write?

Comment: Were you wanting to do greater-than-equal and less-than-equal expressions? Then you would want `Age >= 0` and `Age <= 150`.